# high=None advantage over high=len(a) in bisect.bisect_left

Tags: python

I am learning [8.6. bisect — Array bisection algorithm](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/bisect.html),

`bisect.bisect_left(a, x, lo=0, hi=len(a))` has default values of `lo=0, hi=len(a)`,
When I checked the source code and found that `hi=len(a)` is not set as default directly,

```
def bisect_right(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2  
        if x < a[mid]:
            hi = mid
        else:
            lo = mid+1
    return lo
```

It's achieved by a if check None.

What's the benefit do extra checking than set it as default straightly?

Comment: Because `a` hasn't been defined yet. The parameter doesn't exist until inside the function definition; other parameters can't see it.

Comment: How smart... Could you please transmit the comment to answer as a forwards reference. @chrisaycock

Comment: The other question does not attempt to apply `len` to the parameter, but the accepted answer fully covers your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `a` hasn't been defined yet. The parameter doesn't exist until inside the function definition; other parameters can't see it.